# I want to calculate the json file before post to Cosmos db. cosmos will allow max 2mb file size. How it possible in c#?

Tags: c#, json

I have a json looks below. I want to calculate the size of the json in c# that I got from frontend. I will store the json in cosmos db.

My json is:

```
{
"employeecode": "E1001",
"Employeename": "xyz",
"Address": [
    {
        "RowID": "1",
        "Address1": "58-8",
        "Address2": "rachel street",
        "City": "Newyork",
        "Pin": "100981"
    }
],
"Exp": [],
"Education": [
    {
        "RowID": "1",
        "Secondary": "87.8",
        "School": "xyz",
        "City": "abc"
    },
    {
        "RowID": "2",
        "Higher Secondary": "87.8",
        "School": "xyz",
        "City": "abc"
    },
    {
        "RowID": "3",
        "Btech": "8.8",
        "college": "xyz",
        "City": "abc"
    }
]
}
```

How can I calculte the size of json in c#?

Comment: Just a little note. If you are getting close to the 2MB you are likely doing something wrong that can sting you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to find the string size and it depends on  the encoding of your string `Unicode` or `UTF-8`. The easiest way is using `System.Text.Encoding`

If it is encoded with `UTF-8`

```
var size_in_MB1 = Math.Round(((decimal)Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(json) / 1048576), 2);
```

And, if it is encoded with `Unicode`

```
var size_in_MB2 = Math.Round(((decimal)Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(json) / 1048576), 2);
```

Comment: ASCII? It seems the last one is doing Unicode, as in UTF-16.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, thanks. updated the post